# What is the best way to implement dynamic subdomains in a firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to add a custom subdomain dynamically for the accounts of my firebase project. I am using firebase hosting and was wondering if there is any way to achieve this?

```
acompany.myapphostedwithfirebase.com
bcompany.myapphostedwithfirebase.com
ccompany.myapphostedwithfirebase.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for this.  All configuration must go through the console as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).  If you would like to see some possibility of automating this, [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info! Is there any obvious workaround with google cloud dns you could think off or is this too far fetched?

Comment: I'm sure if there was another supported mechanism, it would be documented.

Comment: Any updates on that?